# Access to PCF app from another machine

Tags: cloud-foundry, pcf

I'm new with the PCF and trying to deploy a simple web-app. I've installed the cf CLI, pcfdev and pushed my app to pcf:

```
cf push test-ui -b staticfile_buildpack
...
name:              test-ui
requested state:   started
instances:         1/1
usage:             256M x 1 instances
routes:            test-ui.local.pcfdev.io
last uploaded:     Thu 23 Aug 13:09:04 +03 2018
stack:             cflinuxfs2
buildpack:         staticfile_buildpack
start command:     $HOME/boot.sh

     state     since                  cpu    memory         disk          details
#0   running   2018-08-23T10:09:17Z   0.0%   5.3M of 256M   25M of 512M
```

So, now, I can access my test app by link test-ui.local.pcfdev.io from the same machine where I've started my pcf instance. But I don't know how to access to this app from another device in the same network.

Could someone tell me what I should do to open my test app from another device in the same network as my local machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution: using the reverse proxy to redirect request from my local port app's url:

(using nginx as example):

```
server {
    listen 8090;
    server_name pcf-rp;

    location / {
       proxy_pass http://test-ui.local.pcfdev.io;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since PCFDev was installed in your local machine. I believe you cannot access the cloud foundry apps outside of your machine unless some networking stuff should be done that provide access to other machines.